# Use the Comparison Test

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Use the Comparison Test to determine for what values of $p$ the integral: $\int_{8}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^p} \ ln(x)  \ dx$ converges. (Use interval notation.) $$\\$$

This is what I have so far:

I'm comparing to $\frac{1}{x}$, which diverges.

I'm unsure of what to do next. I know it starts to converge from 2.

I would really appreciate to your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $p > 1$ choose $a$ such that $0 < a < p-1$.

We have

$$\frac{\ln x}{x^p} = \frac{\ln x^a}{ax^p} < \frac{x^a}{ax^p} = \frac{1}{ax^{p-a}}$$

Since $p-a > 1$ we have convergence for any $p > 1$.

The integral diverges if $p \leqslant 1$ by an easy comparison: $\ln x / x^p > 1/x^p$

Comment: Okay so by interval notion it would be $p$ is $\in$ (1,∞)?

Comment: Yes, we have convergence for $p \in (1,\infty)$ and divergence elsewhere.

Comment: Since $\int_8^\infty \frac{1}{x^p} \, dx$ converges if and only if $p \in (1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $x>1,\ln { x } <x$ so $$\\ \int _{ 8 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { \ln { x }  }{ { x }^{ p } } dx<\int _{ 8 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { dx }{ { x }^{ p-1 } } dx }  } \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ $$ and RHS converges when $p-1>1$ or $p>2$

Comment: So how do I write that in interval notion? Would it be $p$ is $\in$ (1,∞)

Comment: it would be $p\in \left( 2;+\infty  \right) $

Comment: @haqnatural I believe the interval notion would be $p$ $\in$ (1,$+\infty$)

Comment: No, it is what i have written

Comment: Actually @AmR is correct, $p$ $\in$ (1,∞) means that the 1 is not included

Comment: @haqnatural you notion means that the 2 is not included

Comment: @haqnatural your notion would be correct if you used a bracket.

Comment: $\int _{ 0 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { \ln { x }  }{ { x }^{ p } }  } dx\quad $ converges Iff when $p>1$ or $p\in \left( 1;+\infty  \right) $ ,in our case the last integral is $\int _{ 8 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { \ln { x }  }{ { x }^{ p-1 } }  } dx\quad $ so what should be? $p-1>1$ or $p>2$ or $p\in \left( 2;+\infty  \right) $

Answer (score 0):

Take an arbitrary $\eta >8.$ Integration by parts yields$$\int\limits_{8}^{\eta} \frac{1}{x^p}\ln{x} \,dx = -\dfrac{1}{p-1}\int\limits_{8}^{\eta}\ln{x} \, d\left(x^{-(p-1)} \right) = \\ = -\dfrac{1}{p-1}\left(\dfrac{\ln{x} }{x^{p-1}} \Bigg\vert_{8}^{\eta} - \int\limits_{8}^{\eta} \dfrac{dx}{x^p}\right).$$
Then using  L'Hospital's rule,
$$\lim\limits_{\eta\to+\infty} {\dfrac{\ln{x} }{x^{p-1}} \Bigg\vert_{8}^{\eta}} = \begin{cases} 0 - \dfrac{\ln{\eta} }{\eta^{p-1}}  \  \text{(exists and is finite) for } \  p > 1, \\ +\infty, \   \text{if} \  p \leqslant 1  .
\end{cases}$$
The limit $$\lim\limits_{\eta\to+\infty}\int\limits_{8}^{\eta} \dfrac{dx}{x^p}$$ exists for $p>1$ and is infinite, if $ p \leqslant 1  .$